# STS won't respond due to version incompatibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-oxygen

My STS `3.9.4.RELEASE (Build: 201804120921, Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.3a 4.7.3a)` crashes often due to:

```
!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core 1 0 2018-04-26 09:23:26.627
!MESSAGE Error occured processing '/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/context/security.xml'
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setSource(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;
    at org.springframework.security.config.ConcurrentSessionsBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ConcurrentSessionsBeanDefinitionParser.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.config.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.registerConcurrentSessionControlBeansIfRequired(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:261)
    at org.springframework.security.config.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:453)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My project uses `spring-security-core:2.0.8.RELEASE` and `spring-core:3.2.0.RELEASE`, so it's clear that the version of Spring my project uses is not compatible with the version of Spring the IDE uses to analyze the beans. I tried:

1. removing the problematic bean xml from the Config Files (`Project > Properties > Spring > Beans Support > Config Files > Remove above xml`)
2. disabling the bean validation completely on my project (`Project > Properties > Spring > Project Validators > Uncheck Beans Validator`)

but neither of them helped. This error causes:

1. save to freeze (says user operations is waiting for background work to complete, but there is none) even after multiple restarts,
2. shutdown/restart of STS to fail (it simply makes 0 progress), forcing me to kill the process

Any way to resolve this anyone?

Comment: removing the problematic XML from the project configuration is definitely the right approach (that should prevent the above mentioned error to happen). If it continues to happen, it looks like the problematic XML config is still being used to create the beans model. Maybe it is imported by another XML config file and therefore still read? Maybe it is automatically configured for the project? (you can disable the automatic config mechanism in the project settings, too). Can you double check both?

Comment: @MartinLippert I decided to rename that XML file to `security.txt`, but I will definitely have to change it back to `security.xml` when I run my web application. As you pointed out, automatic config detection is something I can disable too.

Comment: @MartinLippert, actually disabling the automatic config detection has worked better for me. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: done... :-) And glad to hear that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks indeed like the used versions of the libraries are not compatible with the Spring version that is used inside of the IDE to create the beans model, so removing that problematic Spring XML config file from the project properties is the right approach for this issue.

But it looks like your XML is still being used to create the internal beans model. Therefore please make sure to disable the automatic config file detection mechanism, otherwise your XML file is being found over and over again by that mechanism.